# Rendering all objects from django REST api using AngularJS

Tags: python, angularjs, django, angularjs-directive, django-rest-framework

Thanks for taking your time to read/give feedback. It'll be quite a lengthy post.

I have recently done the Django + AngularJS tutorial found on https://www.thinkster.io

Based on this tutorial I have built a back/front-end similar to the tutorial, the main difference is that I am using products instead of posts.

For some odd reason the IndexController keeps loading my product directive instead of the products directive.

Using the REST API /api/v1/products/ I can see all the product objects. By which I assume the django part of the application works. Using the Mozilla debugger I can see that the API call works and vm.products (array) is filled with all Product objects. For some odd reason angularJS only shows the last object.

Since this has been the case I have redone the tutorial, which works flawless and rewritten my code, which was no help so I'm turning to you.

This is my ViewSet in my product app:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)
        return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.save()
        return super(ProductViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

This is urls.py in root:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('products', ProductViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    ....
)
```

Now on the AngularJS part. This is the product service I wrote.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.products.services')
        .factory('Products', Products);

    Products.$inject = ['$http'];

    function Products($http) {
        var Products = {
            all: all,
            create:create
        };

        return Products;

        function all() {
            return $http.get('/api/v1/products/');
        }
        function create(name, description, price) {
            return $http.post('/api/v1/products/', {
                name:name,
                description:description,
                price:price
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

This is the product controller I wrote which is pretty much a straight copy of the tutorial.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.products.controllers')
        .controller('ProductsController', ProductsController);

    ProductsController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function ProductsController($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.columns = [];

        activate();

        function activate() {
            $scope.$watchCollection(function () { return $scope.products; }, render);
            $scope.$watch(function () { return $(window).width(); }, render);
        }
        function calculateNumberOfColumns() {
            var width = $(window).width();

            if (width >= 1200) {
                return 4;
            } else if (width >= 992) {
                return 3;
            } else if (width >= 768) {
                return 2;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        function approximateShortestColumn() {
            var scores = vm.columns.map(columnMapFn);

            return scores.indexOf(Math.min.apply(this, scores));

            function columnMapFn(column) {
                var lengths = column.map(function (element) {
                    return element.content.length;
                });
                return lengths.reduce(sum, 0) * column.length;
            }
            function sum(m,n) {
                return m+n;
            }
        }
        function render(current, original) {
            if (current !== original) {
                vm.columns = [];

                for(var i = 0; i < calculateNumberOfColumns(); ++i) {
                    vm.columns.push([]);
                }
                for(var i = 0; i < current.length; ++i) {
                    var column = approximateShortestColumn();

                    vm.columns[column].push(current[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

This is the product directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.products.directives')
        .directive('product', product);

    function product() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                product:'='
            },
            templateUrl:'/static/templates/products/product.html'
        };
        return directive;
    }
})();
```

And this is the products directive.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.products.directives')
        .directive('products', products);

    function products() {
        var directive = {
            controller: 'ProductsController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                products : '='
            },
            templateUrl: '/static/templates/products/products.html'
        };
        return directive;
    }
})();
```

This is app.routes.js, similar to the tutorials routes.js.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.routes')
        .config(config);
    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    function config($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            controller: 'IndexController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: '/static/templates/layout/index.html'
        }).when('/register', {
            controller: 'RegisterController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: '/static/templates/authentication/register.html'
        }).when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: '/static/templates/authentication/login.html'
        }).otherwise('/');
    }
}) ();
```

As seen here the / is controlled by the IndexController so for further clarification: index.controller.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.layout.controllers')
        .controller('IndexController', IndexController);

    IndexController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'Products', 'Snackbar'];

    function IndexController($scope, Authentication, Products, Snackbar) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.products = [];

        activate();

        function activate() {
            Products.all().then(productsSuccessFn, productsErrorFn);

            $scope.$on('product.created', function (event, obj) {
                vm.products.unshift(obj);
            });
            $scope.$on('product.created.error', function () {
                vm.products.shift();
            });

            function productsSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
                vm.products = data.data;
            }
            function productsErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
                Snackbar.error(data.error);
            }
        }
    }
}) ();
```

Now for the HTML pages.

This is index.html

```
<products products="vm.products" ng-show="vm.products && vm.products.length"></products>
```

product.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product__meta">
                    <a>{{ product.name }}</a>
                </div>
                <div class="product__content">
                    <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
                    <p>€{{ product.price }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

products.html

```
<div class="row" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-repeat="column in vm.columns">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <div ng-repeat="product in column">
                <product product="product"></product>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="vm.columns && vm.columns.length">
        <div class="col-sm-12 no-products-here">
            <em>No products</em>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For clarification I'd like to add a screenshot of how the webpage looks like now: http://i68.tinypic.com/1fu0ky.jpg

Desired behavior: List **all** objects returned by /api/v1/products/

Current behavior: Only lists **one (the last)** object returned by /api/v1/products/.

Thank you for taking your time to read.
**edit: ** typo

Comment: everything seems correct. can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle or something similar?

Comment: I am not sure where I can host the app with all it's dependencies and such. If there is a place I can do so I'd gladly provide what is needed.

As for the progress I've made the mozilla debugger states that element.content does not exist in the products controller.

This is the full error message: http://pastebin.com/T7iVZWzD

I have taken the time to examine the code, even rewritten the controller once again yet no avail.

Comment: oh, I forgot that there's django as well :) in this case, I'd suggest you debug your `render` function in `ProductsController` and see whether `$scope.products` actually contains all your products and if it distributes the products correctly.

Comment: $scope.products does contain all the needed Objects from the API. see: http://oi65.tinypic.com/350qi3q.jpg

I am going to have a closer look at the     render function now.

Comment: check out the response from the API call to `GET /api/v1/products` - does it contain the correct information?

Comment: Yes it does. For some unknown reason the Mozilla Debugger won't let me set a breakpoint in the render function, it keeps dropping to the bottom and I can't figure out why.

Comment: you mean you can't set a breakpoint inside `render` function or are you setting it on `$scope.$watchCollection`? Set it in `render` function at the `if (current !== original)` line and check what happens

Comment: The render function breaks because columnMapFn(column) does not work.

`function columnMapFn(column) { var lengths = column.map(function (element) { return element.content.length; }); return lengths.reduce(sum, 0) * column.length; }`

If I replace the `return element.content.length` with any integer it does get all the objects required.

I can't figure out why it's behaving like this.

Comment: most probably it's because your `element.content` is `null/undefined`. Check (1) if the server is responding with the correct output and (2) if the sent data structure matches your frontend structure (I mean do you have a `content` property on the `element`?

Comment: Your comment solved the issue @iulian.

Thank you for that.

The issue that was presented is that I tried to access the `content` property on element. the `element` does not have a content property. It did so in the tutorial by which I wrongly assumed it was a generic property of the element. By reading your (2) I realised the data structure sent by the back end does not have a `content` property. 

Changing the `content` to any property (`name, description, price`) resolves the issue I had.

I'd like to thank you kindly for taking your time to assist @iulian.